# how to save as csv a one-mode network projection of a bipartite network

Tags: r, csv, networking, igraph

Never used R before and this might seem rather stupid question. I have the following transformation of a bipartite network to one-mode and calculate the degree centrality measure.

```
library(igraph)
el <- read.csv("foo.csv", header = T, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = F)
net <- graph.edgelist(as.matrix(el))
V(net)$type <- bipartite.mapping(net)$type
net1mode <- bipartite.projection(net)$proj2
V(net1mode)$deg <- degree(net1mode, loops=F)
```

In R, "net1mode" is shown as "Values" and not "Data". Now, I want to save "net1mode" as csv. Would you please tell me how to do this? Hopefully, it will be a file containing a list of nodes and each has a number in the next column that shows the degree centrality of that node.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

OK! This is how I did it (far from optimal way!):

```
V(net1mode)$deg <- degree(net1mode, loops = F)
options(max.print=1000000)
sink("degree.txt")
V(net1mode)$deg
sink()
```

Then took the text file and did some editing in excel and saved it as csv. Please let me know if you can think of a better way. 
Thank you,